# How do I run command scripts and keystrokes in the background via a button click?

Tags: ms-access-2010

Some employees in our shipping department have been manually entering and editing open orders' shipments in some terribly managed and typo-riddled Excel spreadsheets.

I'm now in the process of creating an Access database that imports the openorder.csv from our ancient UNIX system. Two command scripts (Telnet & FTP) requiring passwords communicate with UNIX to get current data, but the employees are nowhere near technologically literate enough to handle the command prompt screens.

How would I go about having this run in the background with a pop-up box telling the user to wait until the background process has finished?

*Note, I was originally going to have two buttons, one for each, and have the user type in the passwords, but Telnet closes immediately after opening while FTP works fine, but without both, this approach is useless.

I know this is definitely not the most efficient way to do this, but my skills are still lower intermediate, and I can't convince the higher-ups to invest in a server, so I have to do everything with band-aids.

Comment: We're just that far behind... And out in semi-rural NC. Some of our 'management' don't own home computers. This is not what I went to school for, I'm trying to make my life easier, theirs just gets easier as a side-effect.

Comment: Thanks, it is. My main goal is to have a bunch of combo boxes so they stop with the daily typos, if the information can't be imported. 1% typo rate on order number, customer name, etc. It's a nightmare right now.

Comment: I have them entering a lot of data in a form, but I'd like to have as much imported as possible. They'll select dates, use drop-down lists for customers, truck-loaders, etc. They only enter quantities shipped, which I can cross-reference with our shipped.csv later. Instead of them typing in 40 trucks each day with all accompanying information that has already been typed in by our competent order entry team, they'll import all relevant data to prevent redundancy and typos. You can't underestimate how little they must care about data accuracy.